# Carbon Calls failing?

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, macos-carbon

HI All,

My Carbon calls are failing.

I have:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

in my PCH.

I have:

```
/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon
```

in my Header Search Path

But calls like:

```
aDialog = GetNewDialog(16002, NULL,(WindowPtr) (-1L));
```

are failing saying:

```
GetNewDialog not declared in this scope.
```

I am targeting 10.5 64-bit intel.

Comment: `WindowPtr` is deprecated (and has been for all of Carbon's life). The Carbon replacement is `WindowRef`. Essentially the same type, but `WindowRef` more clearly expresses that it's an opaque reference now, like all the other `FooRef` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah, Carbon UI calls are not 64-bit. Nice!

Comment: There is absolutely no valid reason to call GetNewDialog in this day and age.